# Tabs: initial page load showing all tab contents

Tags: jquery, tabs

In my popup footer, I have tabs which on page load show all the contents of every tab/div. But when tab is clicked it performs as it should,  showing only the content from that selected tab/div How would i hide all the other divs/tabs to show only the first active div contents on first view?

This is my code so far:

HTML

```
<ul id='tab'>
    <li><a href='#' class="active" id="tab1">FOLLOW</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' id="tab2">NEWSLETTER</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' id="tab3">SITE INFORMATION</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="cnt-footer">
<div id='cnt-tab1'>
<div id='cnt-tab2'>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#tab a').click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var el = $(this), target = el.attr('id');

    if(el.hasClass('active')) return;

    $('#tab a').removeClass('active');
    el.addClass('active');

    $('#cnt-footer>div').hide();
    $("#cnt-footer>div:not(:first)").hide();
    $('#cnt-footer #cnt-' + target).fadeIn('fast');
  });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/N5SLH/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#cnt-footer>div:not(:first)").hide();
 $('#tab a').click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var el = $(this),
        target = this.id;

    if (el.hasClass('active')) return;

    $('#tab a').removeClass('active');
    el.addClass('active');

    $('#cnt-footer>div').hide();
    $('#cnt-footer #cnt-' + target).fadeIn('fast');
 });
});
```

Comment: A.V. your an absolute genius. Thank you so much for that, it's worked perfectly. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the display of the non-active elements to hidden in the HTML.  This way you don't have rely on the user's browser to hide the elements on `document.ready`

```
<ul id='tab'>
    <li><a href='#' class="active" id="tab1">FOLLOW</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' id="tab2">NEWSLETTER</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' id="tab3">SITE INFORMATION</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="cnt-footer">
<div id='cnt-tab1' style='display: hidden'>
<div id='cnt-tab2' style='display: hidden'>
```